# Created a checkbox list using a data class, but check boxes don't work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I tried to make a checkbox list in Compose, getting the properties from a data class and for some reason, I cannot get the checkboxes to work.

Here's the code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    var tasks = remember {
        mutableListOf(Task("Example Task"), Task("Example Task 2"))
    }
    Column {
        TaskList(tasks)
    }
}

@Composable
fun TaskList(tasks: MutableList<Task>) {
    tasks.forEach { task ->
        ListItem(headlineText = {
            Text(task.title)
        }, leadingContent = {
            Checkbox(checked = task.completed, onCheckedChange = { task.completed = !task.completed })
        })
    }
}

data class Task(
    var title: String, // Title of the task
    var completed: Boolean = false, // Completion state of the task
)
```

Things I already tried:

- Change `var tasks = remember` to `var tasks by remember`: Error. It seems to not work with lists.
- Using a LazyColumn in TaskList instead: No changes.
- Change `fun TaskList(tasks: MutableList<Task>)` to `fun TaskList(tasks: List<Task>)`: No change.
- Change `mutableListOf` for `mutableStateListOf`: No change.
- Use `mutableListOf()` inside of `mutableStateOf()`
- Test if the value changes or not via the log: It's changed but it's not viewed.

Comment: Compose observes changes directly to the elements which for a data class it observes the data class changing not the elements of the data class so in your `onCheckedChange` you should have `task=task.copy(completed= !task.completed)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compose needs to somehow get the information that something changed. That's done with the `State` class - Jetpack compose automatically observes every `State` instance whose value is read in composable function for changes and recomposes every time that happens.

In your code, you don't have any `State` object, so compose is not tracking anything. You can use [`mutableStateListOf`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/4abd809fe6ff660bd768ea850f0f5264835eed79:compose/runtime/runtime/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/SnapshotState.kt;l=229) instead of `mutableListOf`, which would make compose track changes to that list, but still won't solve your problem fully. Compose will recompose every time that list changes, but that's not actually happening in your code - you are only changing variable inside of `Task`, which is not changing the list itself, and jetpack compose doesn't track such changes.

One solution would be to use another `State` in the `Task` class as well:

```kotlin
var tasks = remember {
    mutableStateListOf(Task("Example Task"), Task("Example Task 2"))
}

class Task(
   initialTitle: String,
   initialCompleted: Boolean = false
) {
    var completed: Boolean by mutableStateOf(initialCompleted)
    // only if title can be changed as well, otherwise not needed
    var title: String by mutableStateOf(initialTitle)
    
}

// rest of the code stays unchanged
```

Like this, compose tracks the list changes as well as `completed` property of every `Task` instance, and so it knows when it changes. It's better not to make the class `data class` in such case - you will need custom implementation of `equals` and others that will use the values of the states.

Another option is to create new instance of `Task` every time you need to change any of its properties:

```kotlin
data class Task( // use val instead of var, so you cannot change it
    val title: String,
    val completed: Boolean = false,
)

val tasks = remember {
    mutableStateListOf(Task("Example Task"), Task("Example Task 2"))
}

tasks.forEachIndexed { index, task ->
    Checkbox(
        checked = task.completed,
        onCheckedChange = { checked ->
            tasks[index] = task.copy(completed = checked)
        }
    )
}
```

with that, you are actually changing the list itself, and since it's a state list, compose will be notified about the change.

And by the way, it's a good idea to actually use the boolean value provided by the `onCheckedChange` instead of simply toggling the value.